Power Automate Forward Email Action - how to populate a SharePoint field with original Sender?
I have two flows that work in conjunction with each other.  First flow triggers when an Email is sent to a Group.  It then goes Get Email, Export Email, then Forward Email to our Service account.  The second flow is able to use the trigger "When a New Email arrives", when an email is forwarded to the Service Account.  Once the 2nd flow triggers, it creates a folder in SharePoint, then creates a file out of the email.  This sounds confusing, but it all works fine.  The only problem is the 'Created by' column in SP always only populates my name because the first flow leverages my account to forward the email to the Service account.  So I created a text column called "Submitter", and I'm trying to find a way to identify the original sender, so that I can populate the Submitter column with that individual's name.
So in short:
Email is sent to Group
Email gets forwarded to Service account
2nd flow now triggers and creates a folder & file from that email with attachments

How can I populate a text column with the original sender's name?

